# Why is this list returning Null values?

Tags: python

I'm working on an assignment for my Discrete Structures course that requires me to return a list that creates all possible triplets (order is irrelevant) from the input set A. I am using a function I used earlier in the program that creates a list of pairs and tacking on any elements that are not already in the pair, the removing all repeated triplets. The end set returns all elements as None. What could be causing this?

```
def listPairs(A):
    # type (list) -> list
    B = []
    # Runs through every element in list A
    for x in A:
        y = A.index(x) + 1
        # Makes a pair of every element in A after element x
        while y < len(A):
          B.append([x, A[y]])
          y += 1
    return B


print str(listPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) + " || Expected [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2,     3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 5]"


def listTriples(A):
    # type (list) -> list
    B = listPairs(A)
    C = []
    for y in B:
        for x in A:
            if x not in y:
                C.append(y.append(x))
            if x in y:
                continue
    for z in C:
        if z in C:
            C.remove(z)
    return C


print str(listTriples([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) + " || Expected [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], ...]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first Function listPairs() is ok, however the logic in the second function has some problems. Storing the the current list in each iteration in a temporary variable will help:

```
def listTriples(A):
B = listPairs(A)
C = []
for y in B:
    for x in A:
        if ((x not in y) and (x > y[len(y) - 1])):
            temp = y.copy()
            C.append(temp)
            y.remove(x)
        if x in y:
            continue

return C
```

If you want to print the results of each iteration, the code should look something like this:

```
def listTriples(A):
B = listPairs(A)
C = []
for y in B:
    for x in A:
        if ((x not in y) and (x > y[len(y) - 1])):
            print("x not in y")
            print("Y: ",y)
            print("X: ",x)
            print("y.append(x): ", y.append(x))
            print("new Y (temp):", y)
            print("------")
            temp = y.copy()
            C.append(temp)
            print("C: ", C)
            y.remove(x)
            print("Y:", y)
            print("------\n\n")
        if x in y:
            continue

return C
```

Final results:

```
x not in y
Y:  [1, 2]
X:  3
y.append(x):  None
new Y (temp): [1, 2, 3]
------
C:  [[1, 2, 3]]
Y: [1, 2]
------
x not in y
Y:  [1, 2]
X:  4
y.append(x):  None
new Y (temp): [1, 2, 4]
------
C:  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
Y: [1, 2]
------
x not in y
Y:  [1, 2]
X:  5
y.append(x):  None
new Y (temp): [1, 2, 5]
------
C:  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5]]
Y: [1, 2]
------
x not in y
Y:  [1, 3]
X:  4
y.append(x):  None
new Y (temp): [1, 3, 4]
------
C:  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4]]
Y: [1, 3]
------
x not in y
Y:  [1, 3]
X:  5
y.append(x):  None
new Y (temp): [1, 3, 5]
------
C:  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5]]
Y: [1, 3]
------
x not in y
Y:  [1, 4]
X:  5
y.append(x):  None
new Y (temp): [1, 4, 5]
------
C:  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5]]
Y: [1, 4]
------
x not in y
Y:  [2, 3]
X:  4
y.append(x):  None
new Y (temp): [2, 3, 4]
------
C:  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4]]
Y: [2, 3]
------
x not in y
Y:  [2, 3]
X:  5
y.append(x):  None
new Y (temp): [2, 3, 5]
------
C:  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5]]
Y: [2, 3]
------
x not in y
Y:  [2, 4]
X:  5
y.append(x):  None
new Y (temp): [2, 4, 5]
------
C:  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5]]
Y: [2, 4]
------
x not in y
Y:  [3, 4]
X:  5
y.append(x):  None
new Y (temp): [3, 4, 5]
------
C:  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
Y: [3, 4]
------
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
|| Expected [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `C.append(y.append(x))`. The return value of `y.append(x)` is none - it modifies `y` by appending the `x` value without returning it. You will want to use `y + [x]` instead.